# SimpleInjector equivalent to Unity's AsPerResolve lifetimemanager

Tags: unity-container, simple-injector

Unity has an AsPerResolve lifetime manager. Does SimpleInjector have anything similar? What is it's equivalent?

Unity's definition of AsPerResolve is: Indicates that instances should be re-used within the same build up object graph

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact equivalent of Unity's `AsPerResolve`; or per-object-graph, as it is commonly called. The reason there is no per-object-graph lifestyle in Simple Injector is that it is a very uncommon feature, which can easily cause problems.

In most cases the instance must be scoped per request, such as an [HTTP request](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#per-web-request) or [WCF operation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#per-wcf-operation). With the per-object-graph lifestyle, you can still have multiple instances per request, which can have unwanted side effects and is something that is easily caused incidentally. For instance, it's quite normally to postpone the creation of part of the object graph by using factories, inject a `Func<T>` in a decorator or something like that. Since the object graph is cut in two parts (or more), it will result in extra per-object-graph instances in that request, but this is something that is actually quite hard to detect.

So the way to simulate the per-object-graph lifestyle with Simple Injector is with a scoped lifestyle, most probably the [LifetimeScopeLifestyle](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#per-lifetime-scope).

This means you will have to wrap the call to `GetInstance` with a call to `BeginLifetimeScope()`, for instance:

```cs
using (container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    container.GetInstance<SomeRootObject>();
}
```

This will effectively have the same effect.

Comment: Is "using" the only way to do this? We wrote a wrapper to the container.GetInstance that is generic to any Ioc framework that we plug into our application. So this using statement forces us to write SimpleInjector-specific code which we want to avoid.

Comment: @Ray: Of course not. You can split creation and disposal over multiple methods, as long as you can guarantee that `Dispose` gets called on the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I would think SimpleInjector's PerGraph lifestyle would be what you are looking for.  Check out the [documentation on it](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#pergraph).